# Passing expressions to custom tags in JSP

Tags: jstl, jsp-tags, custom-tag

Hi I just created  custom tag being used in my JSP
The .tld of the tag is something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib>
<tlibversion>1.0</tlibversion>
<jspversion>1.1</jspversion>
<shortname>acma</shortname>
<info>AccountManag</info>
<tag>
    <name>clookup</name>
    <tagclass>taglib.acm</tagclass>
    <info>Customer Lookup</info>
    <attribute>
      <name>cust_id</name>
      <required>true</required>
    </attribute>
</tag>
</taglib>
```

Now the tag works great when i use it with an int value like so
cust_id="1"

```
  <dd:clookup cust_id="1"></dd:clookup>
```

but it doesnt work when i use EL .with it like

```
 <dd:clookup cust_id="${sessionScope.cust.id}"></dd:clookup>
```

All the tutorials start of with int or other data type so i cant locate any resource that might help here.. any suggestions ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Specify `rtexprvalue` in your tld:

```
<attribute>
  <name>cust_id</name>
  <required>true</required>
  <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
</attribute>
```

See [Tag Library Descriptors](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPTags6.html) for more details.

Comment: thanx, bro! it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your EL needs to be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: That was the way i tried it. Thanks for pointing it out. It still doesn't work

Comment: It says that it does not support run time expressions